# how to get the correct date format in Json using Java and MySql

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, jackson

i'm using Java spring MVC with MySql database and i'm trying to use REST api.
The problem is with the date fields, here's my model:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "patient_mesure")
@JsonAutoDetect
public class PatientMesure {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "mesure_patient")
    private float mesure_patient;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mesure", nullable = false)
    private Mesure mesure;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient", nullable = false)
    private Personne patient;
    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date;
    @Column(name = "inserted", nullable = false)
    private Date inserted;
    @Column(name = "updated", nullable = false)
    private Date updated;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And here's my Rest Controller:

```
import com.eheio.spring.models.PatientMesure;
import com.eheio.spring.models.Personne;
import com.eheio.spring.services.PatientMesureService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class PatientMesureRestController {

    private PatientMesureService patientMesureService;

    @Autowired
    public void setPatientMesureService(PatientMesureService patientMesureService) {
        this.patientMesureService = patientMesureService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/getAllMesures")
    public List<PatientMesure> listAllUsers(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession(true);
        Personne personne = (Personne) httpSession.getAttribute("personne");
        return patientMesureService.findMesuresByPatient(personne.getId());
    }
}
```

the results i get :

```
{ id: 1, date: 1527801252000, inserted: 1527801252000, mesure_patient: 50, updated: 1527801252000}
```

How can i get the correct form for the date fields ? something like `2018-05-31 21:14:12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a custom JsonSerialize and format it there, with [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) this way:

First create JsonDateSerializer class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializerProvider;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>{
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        gen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

and then in your getter method:

```
@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

Also, is you are using Java 8 there is [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) which is thread-safe (as @Philippe Marschall pointed out):

```
private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
```

Comment: You shouldn't use static `SimpleDateFormat` they are not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;


    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,  pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS a")
    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,  pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS a")
    @Column(name = "inserted", nullable = false)
    private Date inserted;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,  pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS a")
    @Column(name = "updated", nullable = false)
    private Date updated;
```